# Could not get environment variables: {}

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm attempting to set up a Reddit bot, based on the source-code provided here (https://github.com/bobby-b-bot), however, I keep getting this error.

```
ERROR - Could not get environment variables: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\reddit\reddit_bot.py", line 56, in <module>
logger.info("Got subreddit names: bot running on {} subreddits".format(subreddits.count('+') + 1)) # count '+' sign plus one.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
ERROR - Keyboard termination received. Bye!
```

The code in question is the following:

```
 logger.info("Got subreddit names: bot running on {} subreddits".format(subreddits.count('+') + 1)) # count '+' sign plus one.
```

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Your `subreddits` object is empty, wherever that is defined may be where you will find your issue.

Comment: According to the error, `subreddits` is `None`, so you can't get `count` from it.

Comment: `subreddits is None` however we cannot really tell why that is without the code. StackOVerflow questions should include the code in the question themselves. You did not even take the time to put a link to the specific source file... you just posted a link to 3 different repos. Which one contains the issue?

Comment: I'm not just what to define it as, as I've followed the instructions to the letter provided on github.

Comment: My apologies, here is the source file. https://github.com/bobby-b-bot/reddit/blob/master/reddit_bot.py